# Variance formula does not display correctly

Tags: math-mode

```
\begin{document}
\sigma^2=\frac{\sum(X -\mu)^2}\limits_{i=1}^N{N}
\end{document}
```

This is the code I am using to display variance formula, but it displays 
[image]
instead of

[image]

How should I correct it?

Comment: (1) Always post fully compilable examples, not sniplets, (2) then you would not that that sniplet dows not compile, as it is marh, and math mode has not been initiated. (3) It might be a good idea to read an introduction to LaTeX, e.g. the lshort document on CTAN in order to know the difference between displayed math and inline math.

Comment: @daleif, but this is all the code I have! and it compiles in MikTeX. Thanks for the idea,though, I would surely read the introduction.

Comment: That does not compile in even in MikTeX, there is no `\documentclass`! You also got the syntax all wrong. `\limits` has no place here, use `\sum_{lower}^{\upper} ...`

Comment: I assume there is a lot I don't know in LaTex, but I got the first figure from my TexWorks output (which uses MikTeX). It gave the pdf output, though with a lot of error messages, and that's what I meant by *compiled*.

Comment: That is not what compiled means. If you compile this by hand, using `pdflatex file.tex` in a dos promt, you will notice that it will fail. Most editors run LaTeX in a mode that does not stop at errors, it makes an assumption and tries to continue. That is why your document seems to compile, in that it gives a PDF. But a document that does not compile withput errors, does, by doefinition, not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE can not work! For math expression you need math environment, for inline formulas `$ ... your math expression ...$`, for display formula (stand alone in text) `\begin{equation} .... \end{equation}` for numbered equations and for non-numbered `\[ ... \]`. For math environments exist other possibilities, which available with us packets as `amsmath` etc.

Also the formula is ill formed. Correct code is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}% or any other document class, as article, book ..
\begin{document}
$\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (X -\mu)^2}{N}$
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: What is {standalone}? I don't have it in my MikTeX, it prompts me to install.

Comment: just replace it with `article`, `standalone` is not suppose to be used in normal user documents

Comment: @JasonStack, `standalone` is wonderfull package and document class intended to show text, figures, etc on whole "page", actually, it accommodate size of page to content. It is worth to install it, read a documentation for all possibilities and than exploit its possibilities. Given MWE also works (as I mentioned in comment in code) if you replace it with`documentclass{article}`.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko, _standalone_ and _preview_ packages are really cool! I just installed them and got big previews with adjustable zoom for the output.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a better MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\sigma^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N  (X -\mu)^2}{N}
\]
\end{document}
```